# compare time range & fixed time between different sheets in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, libreoffice-calc

I have 3 sheets in excel

Sheet 1 contains column Arrival-Time in 24hrs format

**Arrival-Time**

11:00
22:00
05:00
09:00

Sheet 2 contains column Departure-time in 24hrs format

**Departure-time**

14:00
23:00
18:00
10:00

Sheet 3 contains column Planned-time in 24hrs format

**Planned-time**

15:00
18:00
3:00 - 12:00
12:00 - 16:00

Now I want a formula if Planned time is between arrival-time & departure-time then update a column DELIVERY to YES else NO.

But unfortunately my planned-time column contain both, time range ( 3:00 - 12:00) & fixed time (3:00).

So how do I write a generic formula to update DELIVERY column ?? as my planned-time column contain both time-range & fixed time.

Comment: Do the Planned-time entries only relate to that row in each of the Arrival-time and Departure-time entries?

Comment: @TimEdwards : Yes it relate only to that row of arrival & departure time. 
So ill compare A1 , B1 & C1.
Where A is Arrival-time
B is Depart time
C is Planned time

Comment: Will the ranges always be the ones in 12hr clock or will you get entries like 13:00 - 16:00 or 11:00AM. Would these always be written in the same way or would you sometimes get 11AM. If you're going to have to write a logical formula you need to think about the possibilities.

Comment: Sorry for more questions but also noticed that you have both : and . separating hours and minutes, would you use anything else also that would need considering? Also would there be a need for seconds at all as that'll make it messy as well?

Comment: @TimEdwards :  sorry for the confusion.
12:00 - 16:00   -- Ranges will be in 24hr format with :  as delimiter  
Also there won't be seconds only hour & minutes

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it could be done in a tidier way (you could combine some of these into even larger formulas) but I've got the below.

Not exhaustively tested but I think it does what is needed.

The theory is to work out what kind of input you have and then deal with it accordingly, the way I see it you have clock-type and range variables.

**Therefore first two "helper" columns are Clock-type (B2):**

`=IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="M","12","24")`

**then Range (C2):**

`=NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-",A2)))'

**I then have four columns to calculate the start and end of ranges in both 12 hour and 24 hour clocks (sorry but these are long!), D2 is:**

`=IF(MOD(IF(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"),2)="AM",VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"))-2)),VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"))-2))+0.5)*2,1)=0,IF(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"),2)="AM",VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"))-2)),VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"))-2))+0.5)-0.5,IF(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"),2)="AM",VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"))-2)),VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2),".",":"))-2))+0.5))`

**E2 is:**

`=IF(MOD(IF(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"),2)="AM",VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"))-2)),VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"))-2))+0.5)*2,1)=0,IF(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"),2)="AM",VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"))-2)),VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"))-2))+0.5)-0.5,IF(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"),2)="AM",VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"))-2)),VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2),".",":"))-2))+0.5))`

**F2 is:**

`=VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-2))`

**G2 is:**

`=VALUE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)+2))`

**If you're still awake we then move onto working out if the types hit your criteria.
H2 (24hrs and Not a Range) is:**

`=AND(A2>=Sheet1!A2,A2<=Sheet2!A2)`

**I2 (12hrs and Not a Range) is:**

`=AND(IF(RIGHT(A2,2)="AM",VALUE(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2)),VALUE(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2))+12)>=Sheet1!A2,IF(RIGHT(A2,2)="AM",VALUE(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2)),VALUE(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2))+12)<=Sheet2!A2)`

**J2 (24hrs and Is a Range) is:**

`=OR(AND(F2>=Sheet1!A2,F2<=Sheet2!A2),AND(G2>=Sheet1!A2,G2<=Sheet2!A2))`

**K2 (12hrs and Is a Range) is:**

`=OR(AND(D2>=Sheet1!A2,D2<=Sheet2!A2),AND(E2>=Sheet1!A2,E2<=Sheet2!A2))`

**Now we come to your Delivery column, I've gone with TRUE / FALSE rather than "Yes" / "No", this just uses the types and the results above in order to use the right one for the right scenario:**

`=IF(B2=24,IF(C2,J2,H2),IF(C2,K2,I2))`

**As I've said, not been tested but hopefully if I have made mistakes (which is quite possible in all that) you should be able to take the logic and then make any adjustments needed.**

Comment: thanks for the solution, However I could not make it work.
Can u share the excel sheet?

Comment: I don't have dropbox or similar to share it on, so I don't think that's an option. What's the error or is it not calculating how you expect?

Comment: My Test data : 
Sheet1.A2 = 11:00  
Sheet2.A2 = 11:55
Sheet3.A2 = 12:00 - 16:00  

After applying your formula  : Following output  :

Comment: My Test data : 
Sheet1.A2 = 11:00  
Sheet2.A2 = 11:55
Sheet3.A2 = 12:00 - 16:00  

After applying your formula  : Following output  :  

24  |  TRUE  |  0.5  |  1.16667  |  0.5  |  0.666667  |  FALSE  |  #VALUE!  |  FALSE  |  FALSE  |  FALSE  

So couldn't understand logic & there is error in I2